# How to resolve TypeError using <= between 'float' and 'NoneType'?

Tags: python

```
def can_pay_bills(current_balance):
    monthly_bills=0
    monthly_bills=float(input("What is the sum of all of your monthly bills this month?"))

    if monthly_bills <= current_balance:
        print("There is enough money in your account to pay your bills this month.")
    elif monthly_bills > current_balance:
        print("You do not have enough money in your account to pay your bills this month.")
    elif monthly_bills == current_balance:
        print("You have exactly enough money in your account to pay your bills this month and not a cent to spare.")
```

[image]

Comment: How are you calling the function and what is `current_balance`?

Comment: did you supply the `current_balance` argument as a float ? Right now, Python is recognizing `current_balance` as NoneType meaning you forgot to define it somewhere

Comment: Fix `get_balance` so it doesn't return `None`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @It_is_Chris: Then wouldn't there be a complaint about `get_balance` being undefined?

Comment: `some_float == some_other_float` is a bit risky too.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, current balance would be undefined. I updated the comment to one that actually makes sense.

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make comparisons between numbers and a `None` object. Pass the value of the argument to the function at the time of the call

```
can_pay_bills(10)
```

or specify a default value

```
def can_pay_bills(current_balance=10):
    monthly_bills=0
    ...
```

The error traceback indicates that your internal function `get_balance` returns `None`

Comment: You my friend, are a life saver! Thank You so much!